# rails console - run a block of code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I understand how to run a simple piece of code in rails console. say

```
 Swimming::Student.create(:name="Jerry")
```

How do I run a big piece of code (many lines)

```
 Swimming::Student.all.each{ |student|
     student.attended = flase
     student.save
 }
```

Comment: just enter it like that. The whole block is executed, once it's complete

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just hit enter, as you'd expect:

```
$rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
2.0.0p0 :001 > Student.all.each do |student| #enter
2.0.0p0 :002 >     puts student #enter
2.0.0p0 :003?> end #enter
# here comes the output
```

Comment: Also, semicolon: `Product.all.each{|p| puts p; p.shown = true}